# Changing created, modified, accessed times of files

Tags: windows, file-management

How can I change (preferably in batches) creation, last-modified and last-access times of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**FileDate Changer**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/filedatech.html) will do this.

You can simply drag and drop into the Filename box and apply changes in batches.

Tested up to Windows 7, it is free and only a couple of KB.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell, something like:

```
$date = Get-Date "2010-01-31 10:11:12"
Get-ChildItem *.foo | Foreach-Item {
    $_.LastWriteTime = $date
    $_.LastAccessTime = $date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Take Command Console LE**](http://www.jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm) (TCC LE), a free souped-up replacement for the command prompt, has a [`touch`](http://www.jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?touch.htm) command that can change the creation, last modification and last access times and dates for files. It can of course run batch files.

The parameters to use are /D (for date) and /T (for time):

**/D**

```
On an LFN drive, you can specify which of the date fields should be set by appending a, c, or w to the /D option:

a Last access date 
c Creation date  
w Last modification (write) date
```

**/T**

```
On an LFN drive, you can specify which of the time fields should be set by appending a, c, or w to the /T option:

a Last access time (on VFAT volumes access time is always midnight). 
c Creation time  
w Last modification (write) time
```

Answer (score 0):

[SKTimeStamp](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/SKTimeStamp) shell extension.

[image]